# Is ready to watch or Is ready to be watched?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

I need to know which one is correct between the options in the bracket below:

> The usher said that this film is ready (to watch/to be watched) at
> 3:30. Let's go home it's still 8:00 in the morning.

Please also explain if there's a big difference between them (the expressions in the bracket). Can they possibly be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is ellipsis and personification.

> The film is ready [for you] to watch at 8:00 p.m.

is an example of ellipsis. Words needed to make the utterance a complete thought were omitted because they were assumed to be obvious and unessential.

> The film is ready to be watched at 8:00 p.m.

is an example of personification. The film is assumed to be a person who has times of readiness and times of unreadiness.

**EDIT**: Actually, there is a third option that also makes sense and involves ellipsis.

> The film [will be made] ready at 8:00 p.m.

Ellipsis and personification are part of English and must make learners crazy until they ask whether there are parallels in their native languages.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand it correctly, they are all fine, but have different grammar?

Comment: They are all grammatical. For some reason, however,  the personification one is far and away the most common. My guess is that people intuitively liken movies to plays. Actors in plays are seldom ready to put on a show at 4:00 a.m. That is a guess. In any case, I personally would not choose any of these (to my ears) semi-illiterate locutions. I’d say “The film will not be shown until 8:00 p. m.”

Comment: If I may know, what would you choose other than those options. Thanks so much for the answer by the way.

Comment: @user516076 I think your question and my edit of my comment cross-posted.